# how to write nested query for this scenario?

Tags: mysql

**cars_aircraft table**

```
id, aircraft_name, home_base_address,alternate_base_airport 

1 ,     MIG 20   ,         77   ,               80

2   ,   MIG 30   ,         80       ,50
```

**cars_airport table**

```
id ,airport_city , airport_name

1    ,  mumbai      ,    CST

2   , pune       ,    PIA
```

i need aircraft_name,airport_name as a result for **airport_city="mumbai".**

Condition is that in search not only searched city's aircraft will come as
well as neighour city's aircraft should also come.

i.e neighour city of mumbai is pune(based on alternative_base_airport value of mumbai which is home_base_address of pune , so for mumbai search mumbai and pune both should come)

please help

Answer (score 0):

The second table doesn't look like it's got any association with the first... but this is something you can do:

Select * from table where airport="Mumbai" 
union 
select * from table where home_base in (select alternative_base from table where homebase = "Mumbai")